# Reopen: Why don't women cover their heads?

Tags: discussion

Please help me understand why this isn't a good question.
[Why don't women cover their heads](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/why-dont-women-cover-their-heads)  I've reworded it to better fix the Q&A format.  However, my accepted answer will be more of my opinion (IMHO).  I would rather not do that.

As a "Should a Christian..." question, it would be easier to select the best answer with this criteria:  "Yes, they should because it says here and here and an example...." or "No, they shouldn't because it says here and here and an example..."  That is, I can judge the best answer by who has the most supporting information.  However now, I have to judge which is the best answer.  The difference is small, but obvious to me.

Caleb asked these questions:

> What would you like to come away having learned something about? Who
>   does? Who doesn't? Why those who don't don't?

What I'm looking for is:

- Why orthodox Christianity does not promote this?
- When did it stop?
- <strike>Is it a good idea to promote this? (should I have a discussion with
  my wife?)</strike>

Comment: Your first two bullet points could be great questions, but those aren't what you asked. Ask those and you'd be fine. The third one is exactly the kind of thing that doesn't fly here, and that's pretty much what you asked the first time around. Your ends are part way there, but it's still messy.

Comment: I modified the question to ask it.  I should have been more direct in the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the original version of this meta question:

**The work you did to eventually make a real case for the question in this meta post** (that eventually made it a decent question) **is the work that should have gone into the original question on the main site in the first place**. The original showed zero research effort and didn't fit any of our site guidelines.

---

The current version of this meta question doesn't seem to call for an answer too me since the question is taken care of. Since it doesn't seem useful for anything other than posterity, here's  are my comments to your edits (no obsolete).

In response to the original version of the question:

> "Should Christians_*_*" questions in general boil down to searches for truth on an issue. As far as the scope of this site is concerned, truth questions are out of bounds. If you want to re-work this so that it asks something ABOUT CHRISTIANITY -- as in who believes what and why -- that would be fine, but trying to resolve whether something SHOULD be one way or another is not a constructive question for this format.

In response to the first round of edits:

> The edits to this give the question a fractured personality. What would you like to come away having learned something about? Who does? Who doesn't? Why those who don't don't? Just throwing a topic out there for discussion isn't what this site is good for, be specific about what you'd like to learn. Keep in mind you can't cover both sides of an unresolved issue with a single question.

Comment: I disagree that the original question showed "zero" research.  However, I understand why you felt that it didn't fit.  However I'd like to point out that others didn't agree that the original question was bad.  However, we all know not to upset the Caleb. ;)

Comment: @DanAndrews: Ok so _zero_ was hyperbole because you at least found the verse reference in the NT. But seriously you see the difference between the amount of effort it took to think though what would make it a good question and vs the original right? Maybe _next to nothing_ would have been more technically accurate. Also, several others did agree that the original was bad (I wasn't the only or even the first commentor or VTC), it just wasn't unanimous because one person noted they didn't see the issue.

Comment: honestly, I see the hard work it took to appease you.  It was after all, a question posed while "on the run" in the real world.  That is, I had a conversation in the office with someone, I researched and found that they were right, I thought I'd post the question here to get other's answers.  Maybe that's not the proper use of SE. Further more...

Comment: ...  When you demand people change questions and answers (to the same question), at some point, you're just talking to yourself.  I would like to see more community involvement in closing, opening, and suggesting better question and answers.  Not just the mods.  You're working too hard my brother.

Comment: @DanAndrews SE caters to experts, and this site tends towards the academic, not on the fly / off the top of your head stuff. And, if you'll note, _two non-mod community members jumped in close votes and a comment before I stopped by_. I took the time (from mobile on the run myself) to leave detailed comments about what the issue was and how you could fix it. You're welcome.

Comment: @DanAndrews Also, **three of your four previous closed questions were closed by 5 community members, zero mods**. The other one, which I closed, was deleted by votes from solely community members, no mods. I think the community _is_ involved here, not just mods.

Comment: please don't take me the wrong way.  I'm not saying that I don't appreciate you time and effort.  I'm saying that you're working too hard.  You even mention making suggestions from a cell phone.  It would be nice to see more non-mods put in an effort.  However, looking in the mirror, I could have put in more effort myself - which is the point of your answer.

Comment: @DanAndrews: If that's what you're trying to say, it seems to me you are saying in in the wrong place to the wrong person. I started this conversation by saying you weren't putting in enough effort, then you complained I was putting in too much and the rest of the community not enough. If you think people ought to put in effort, set an example yourself then get out there and recruit them. Comments on my post doesn't seem like the place for that call to action if that's what you are really trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the original question:

> When I first heard about this, I thought, "oh, this must be from the old test!" However I was wrong. Per the 1 Corinthians 11:6, should women wear a covering such as the Hijab?

That's just lazy.  It didn't even spell (out/correctly?) "Old Testament".  And while your surprise is understandable, it seems like the first thing you did was to run out and ask a question here.  I typed your question into [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Should%20women%20cover%20their%20heads?) and got plenty of helpful looking results including an entire [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_headcovering) on the issue.  (It's not a very balanced article, but that's a different problem.)

After much work the heart of the question is now:

> - Why don't more Christian women wear a covering such as the Hijab?
> - Are there many (any) mainstream / orthodox denominations that promote head coverings for women?
> - When did this tradition stop?

The first question is ridiculous on it's face: [Hijab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijab) is clearly a Muslim concept.  Christian women might wear it when living in a Muslim country for the sake of cultural sensitivity.  What you meant ask was why Paul's instructions on this point aren't more generally followed.  Nobody who follows Paul's instructions would call their headcovering a "hajab".  Our site works best when asking about the doctrines of particular groups.  A better question might have been:

> Why don't more Catholic women wear headcoverings?

(But don't ask that since Wikipedia already answered it.)

That Wikipedia article answers the second question better than any of us could.

The final question is perhaps interesting, but it's lost in all the other things you are doing in the question.

### Questions are not a soapbox!

Which brings me to my main objection with this whole thing: the question seems to be more concerned with pointing out the conflict between the text and orthopraxy than with trying to learn.  I have some ideas on how to answer your question, but I don't think you care to hear them.  Maybe I'm wrong, but that's the impression your question makes on me.  Why should I give you even a few moments of my time if you don't care to learn anything?

### We have a higher standard for questions.

You [wrote](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/reopen-why-dont-women-cover-their-heads#comment3133_1400):

> And yes, I already admitted that it was a fly by post. Lazy, eh, I guess. It's not much different than someone who answers a question only to come back and clean it up later - which happens a lot.

But it *is* different.  When you ask a question, you are initiating a conversation topic.  When you answer a question, you are responding to a public request.  We have higher standards for questions because it's not a trivial thing to request the attention of every other participant in the site.  Bad, lazy, fly-by questions waste the time of dozens of people.

Please understand that I respect and admire your evident persistence.  But it angers me that you are trying to justify a lazy question.  Why not save us all the trouble of critiquing your questions by just asking better questions in the first place?  I could understand if you honestly didn't know how, but you're obviously a smart person.

Comment: "Christian women aren't generally Muslim" - that pretty ridiculous that you'd say that.  Muslims are Muslim and Christians are Christian and a Hijab is a covering.  You don't have to be Muslim to wear one.  Please don't keep us in suspense, enlighten us with the answer which you're holding on to.

Comment: And yes, I already admitted that it was a fly by post.  Lazy, eh, I guess.  It's not much different than someone who answers a question only to come back and clean it up later - which happens a lot.

Comment: @Dan Andrews: I've updated my answer.  Feel free to comment as you see fit, but be aware that I need to take a step back and avoid saying anything else for a while.

Comment: I admit that I should have thought out my question a little more or taken a little more time to develop it before starting to type.  I believe the backlash from this is a bit extreme - but that's my belief, nobody else has to agree with it.  I wonder if I would have NOT said, "... such as the Hijab?" would it have made a difference.  While I used the hijab in my question, I was using it as an example of a head covering.  One that is not very different then every image of Mary that I've ever seen.